Automatic way to check correct inclusion of C++ standard headers
The following C++ code compiles fine with GCC (demo):
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  auto j = std::move(-1);
}

The problem is that std::move is provided by the utility standard header, not iostream. This actually makes the code non-portable according to the C++ standard.
I there any way (e.g., some code analysis tool) that would be able to report such problems, ideally for all std::... entities used in some particular source/header file? (My motivation stems from checking student homeworks. I would like to automate as much tests as possible, since manually searching for all std::... names and checking corresponding headers inclusion is tedious.)

Include what you use (IWYU) should find that, and also give hints about includes that can be omitted completely or replaced by a smaller library.

for every symbol [...] that you use [...] should #include a .h file that exports the declaration of that symbol. The include-what-you-use tool is a program [...] to analyze #includes of source files to find include-what-you-use violations, and suggest fixes for them.

It may not always work reliably, because

This is experimental software, as of June 2024.
Include-what-you-use makes heavy use of Clang internals, and will occasionally break when Clang is updated.

[Source]
Unfortunately I have not set this up myself yet, but it was recommended by C++ trainer Klaus Iglberger, who I trust. Our build is currently MSVC and IWYU only works if we can build our application with Clang, if I got that correctly. However, that should be much more simple for student assignments than for our 5MLoC application.

Thanks, I didn't know this tool. I will give it a try.
